# Do I have to load 60 fonts to support 60 language in website?

Tags: javascript, css, reactjs, frontend, webfonts

I am making a website in react that will support 60 language . But I am not sure how to develop that website . Do I have to  load 60 fonts (like by CDN links) in my website so that it support all languages correctly? or there is any other better approach?

Comment: That depends on the alphabet those languages use and the alphabets supported by your fonts.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

**TL;DR** No, you don't. Just use a font that supports most latin languages + fonts for special cases like chinese. Don't include third-party links to load your resources!

**Exact explanation**

**At first:** you might know, most of the languages in the world are using the latin alphabet + some extra letters. If you have one font supporting this alphabet + extra letters (ASCII) you can also support most languages like french, German, English and so on. So you don't need exactly 60 fonts for 60 languages. Just 1 for latin-languages with all needed letters + special fonts.

**Secondly** you might think about optimizing your ui for other special languages whose native speakers are used to read their letters in a different way than countries like English one (reading from top-bottom to left-right, or right-left to top-bottom).

**Third**: don't use links to load resources from third party. If you use this links you might be fine but as son as the resource you get behind this uri vanishes your ui might not work properly. Best practices are: download your fonts from Google fonts and place them in a resource folder of your app. In case of react place it in `src/fonts/someOtherDirForLanguagesMaybe`.

Reason: React can bundle your resources in "src" with webpack and can reduce the network traffic drastically. And just load the font the user really needs. So a native English-speaker will not use any Chinese letters.

**Fourth**: When you develop your website you should not try to support all languages at once. At first do a concept about your website and structure your ui well. Start with basic languages like English/German/Spanish/Frensh (all latin-based languages) and with some useful features try then out other languages if you reached a point where you think it might be useful to support some other languages.

Hopefully this answers your question deeply. :)

Answer (score 1):

Depending on the languages you need to support and the font(s) you wish to use, you may well need to use multiple fonts, There are many fonts that cover a lot of different languages and typesets though.

[Google Noto font](https://www.google.com/get/noto/) is an example of a font that tries to support as many languages as possible

Comment: wouldn't loading too many  fonts at once will  affect site site performance?

Comment: Yes, too many would affect performance. You shouldn't really need more than 3-4 different fonts I'd imagine, since most languages share character sets. Optimising so that only the required font(s) for the user's language are downloaded would be a good idea